# Unable to instantiate receiver in BroadcastReceiver SMS

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Why I have this error :

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(854): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(854): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.android.GPS21.SmsReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.GPS21.SmsReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02ef0
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.GPS21.SmsReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02ef0
```

This is my onReceive events:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Recieved a message");
  if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
   // if(message starts with SMStretcher recognize BYTE)
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   // The SMS-Messages are 'hiding' within the extras of the Intent.
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   if (bundle != null) {

    // Get all messages contained in the Intent
    // Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent) does not
    // work anymore hence the below changes

    Object[] pduObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduObj.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pduObj.length; i++)
     messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduObj[i]);
    // Feed the StringBuilder with all Messages found.
    for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages) {
     sb.append("SMS Received From: ");
     // Sender-Number
     sb.append(currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
     sb.append("\nMessage : ");
     // Actual Message-Content
     sb.append(currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
    }
   }
   // Logger Debug-Output
   Log.i(LOG_TAG, "[SMSApp] onReceive: " + sb);

   // Show the Notification containing the Message.
   Toast.makeText(context, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

In debug that onReceive() is error.

I just make BroadcastReceiver to receive SMS and show in notification Toast..

And I try send SMS from DDMS and that error appear..

Answer (score 13):

Your manifest claims you have a class named `com.android.GPS21.SmsReceiver`, and Android cannot find it.

Comment: com.android.GPS21.SmsReceiver is the class which onReceiver located.

I think that's not the problem..

Comment: @fadli wdt: I am telling you that this is what your error says. If that is not your error, then we cannot help you. Though I should point out that you will get the same error message -- I think -- if you are missing the superclass (e.g., your superclass for `com.android.GPS21.SmsReceiver` cannot be found). Also, since you do not work for Google, please do not use the `com.android` namespace. Use one based on a domain name you own.

Comment: Sorry for namespace. I just follow the tutorial said.

Comment: Note that even if your project contains a `com.android.GPS21.SmsReceiver`, that class must also extend `BroadcastReceiver`.  If you have defined `onReceive`, for example, but do not declare it as an `@Override` (without extending) you won't get an error, but you will get the above exception at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question and I'm not sure that this was your trouble, but I just had this issue. Within Eclipse, I created the *folder* (really a *package*) in the wrong place. For example

**Incorrect**

[image]

The reason this is incorrect is that the **Broadcast** folder/package isn't within the namespace like you expect. This happens if you right click on **My Program/src** and create the package there. Notice that it is **My Program/src/Broadcast** which is what is wrong.

The reason is that the *SmsReceiver* class isn't in your namespace. In this case you may have something like this in your manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".Broadcast.SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When this is triggered, the **SmsReceiver** class is NOT found and you'll get the error.

**Correct**

[image]

The correct way to do this, and get the package in the proper namespace is to right click on **com.example.my.program** and create it there instead. Notice that it is **My Program/src/com.example.my.program.Broadcast** which is now correctly in the same namespace.

This will be found in by the app with the same manifest code above.

Comment: I know that it has been a while since this was posted, but I wanted to thank @Kirk for the detail. Due to it's thoroughness, it helped me resolve my own issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your broadcastReceiver class must be a public class by example

public class ReceptorLlamadas extends BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the complete path to your broadcastReceiver, I mean, if in your manifest file you jave package="com.myapp", but your MySmsBroadcast.java is not exactly under myapp package (it's on myapp.smsStuff.MySmsBroadcast, for example), in the

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well. In my case, my Virtual Device was corrupted.

Try creating a new one and running with it. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

you can write the receiver as "static".
In the program my.sample, should write receiver " static SimpleSmsReceiver

Answer (score 1):

Provide fully qualified class name, That worked for me

Like this : 
*

```
<receiver android:name="com.zolipe.communitycensus.util.CensusReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
          <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

*

Answer (score 0):

I've got a same error. 
After I modified the "AndroidManifest.xml" like this, the error is resolved.

`receiver android:name=".SimpleSmsReceiver"`

->

`receiver android:name=".SimpleSMSReceiver"`

The error was like this.

```
...
01-13 10:23:10.787: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver my.sample.SimpleSmsReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.sample.SimpleSmsReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/my.sample-2.apk]
01-13 10:23:10.787: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)
01-13 10:23:10.787: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-13 10:23:10.787: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
```

Comment: What is the different in your AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a public constructor without parameters.
For example I have my own BroadcastReceiver implementation that receives some properties on the constructor. After I added a public default (without parameters) constructor, it works perfectly.