# start my service on phone restart in android

Tags: android, boot, restart

I am making app which tracks user location continuously, so far i have been able to make a successful receiving of its ordinate on location change, but if he is restarting the phone than i am not able to start my service without user again opening the app.

- Manifest.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.aa.gpsdemo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="8"
  android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>   
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


  <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <activity
      android:name="com.aa.gpsdemo.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
      <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.aa.gpsdemo.StartMyServiceAtBootReciever" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <receiver
      android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true"
      android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver> 
      </application>

      </manifest>
  ```
- StartMyServiceAtBootReciever.java

  ```
  package com.aa.gpsdemo;
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;

  public class StartMyServiceAtBootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
      Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.aa.gpsdemo.BackgroundService");
      context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
      }
   }
  ```
- BackgroundService.java

  ```
  package com.aa.gpsdemo;

  import android.app.Service;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.IBinder;
  import android.location.LocationManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.StrictMode;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import android.location.Criteria;

  public class BackgroundService extends Service {

  private static NewLocationListener mylistner=null;
  private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
  private Context context = null;

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  }

  mylistner = new NewLocationListener(context);
  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
  criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
  criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
  criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
  LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  String bestProvider=locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
  locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,1000, 5, mylistner);



  }

      }
  ```

where i am going wrong any help would be highly appreciated on restart of a phone i get demoapp has stopped i tried putting toast on reciever but that toast also are not coming at present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make Sure u have the permission in AndroidManifest File :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Change this to :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,BackgroundService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but this doesn't work its still not giving a toast or a log in receiver and giving unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: i just tried Alok its working fine for me can u post the LogCat ??Make Sure receiver and Service is properly referenced in ManifestFile

Comment: this is my manifest section where i m binding service and reciever

<service android:name=".BackgroundService" android:label="Background Service">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.aa.gpsdemo.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <receiver
      android:name="com.aa.gpsdemo.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true"
      android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

Comment: try this 

 <service android:name=".BackgroundService">
</service>  

 <receiver android:name="com.aa.gpsdemo.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>

Comment: this is what i am getting in logcat

08-18 20:24:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 20:24:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.aa.gpsdemo.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aa.gpsdeo.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver

Comment: check whether u are giving proper path for receiver in Manifest file fyi [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619049/unable-to-instantiate-receiver-in-broadcastreceiver-sms)

Comment: sorry for late reply for me toast in reciever class has start coming but still in service its not starting.Working on it and thanks for ur help

Comment: as i said make sure the service name is proper in manifest file and if its answered please upvote/accept the answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35698/discussion-between-alok-agarwal-and-srikanth-gr)

Answer (score 0):

**RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED**: Broadcast Action: This is broadcast once, after the system has finished booting. It can be used to perform application-specific initialization, such as installing alarms. You must hold the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in order to receive this broadcast.

[Refrence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)

[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed)

Comment: Thanks for your time and i have updated my manifest file i have given the permission that you are referring to

Comment: @AlokAgarwal try to start your service from onReceive