# BroadcastReceiver not firing for network connection changes

Tags: android, connection, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to listen for changes in network connectivity. My broadcast receiver doesn't seem to be firing when I switch in or out of airplane mode. I'm not sure if this is because I don't have it registered correctly or if maybe airplane mode changes don't cause this to fire. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<receiver android:name=".NetworkReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My broadcast receiver class:

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        prefEditor = prefs.edit();

        Boolean has_connection = prefs.getBoolean("has_connection", false);
        prefEditor.putBoolean("has_connection", !has_connection);
        prefEditor.commit();

        System.err.println("Network Receiver notified of a connectivity change!");
        System.err.println("New has_connection: " + !has_connection);

    }

}
```

Also, after the app runs for about 45 seconds, it suddenly crashes with the following error:

```
09-06 21:29:48.775: E/AndroidRuntime(15613): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.mysite.myapp.NetworkReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysite.myapp.NetworkReceiver
```

Comment: Please refer to this answer for pre and post lollipop devices.[Very Useful for connectivity detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37404841/2581109)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a thread about a similar issue to what you're having.  Maybe one of these answers will help:

[Unable to instantiate receiver in BroadcastReceiver SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619049/unable-to-instantiate-receiver-in-broadcastreceiver-sms)

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem was that my receiver is in a package called 'database' which is in the 'src' folder. Thus, my manifest needed to be `<receiver android:name="database.NetworkReceiver" >` Now it is receiving connectivity changes and no more crashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have u add permission in the AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Yes. I should have posted that. I'll edit my post to show that. I'm also getting an error message after the system fully boots that crashes it. I'll also post this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't give relative names for receiver. Give full package name as well. For example,

```
<receiver android:name="com.YouPackageName.NetworkReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
```

This should solve your problem for sure!

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that a couple of different ways, but same result. I have this class inside of a package called 'database'. So I've tried `com.mysite.myapp.NetworkReceiver` and also `com.mysite.myapp.database.NetworkReceiver`. Unfortunately, neither seems to solve the issue. In fact, I get the exact same error under all three settings.