# BroadcastReceiver Intent filter for network operator change

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Before anything I want to say that I did search about this.
My goal is to detect if the smartphone is on roaming to trigger a notification to the user. I want the notification to be triggered when the device handsoff to a foreigner mobile provider.

My first thought was to register a BroadcastReceiver with the apropriate intent filter, because I'm sure the OS detects when the SIM is roaming.

Based on other posts here on stackoverflow I codded this:

On AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="(...).RoamingBrocastReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My RoamingBrocastReceiver class is like this:

```
public class RoamingBrocastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = RoamingBrocastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private Context context;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onReceive()");
        this.context = context;
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephony.isNetworkRoaming()) {
            String notificationTitle = "Sample title";
            showNotification(notificationTitle);
            String contryIso = telephony.getNetworkCountryIso();
            Log.v(TAG, "Roaming is on: country ISO: " + contryIso);
        }
    }

}
```

Based on my tests the android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE action is only triggered when data connections are change (example wifi, 3g/4g data), but never when the network changes.
I've done some tests with a local and a foreigner SIM card and this action is never triggered when I change the SIM card on my Nexus 5 with the device on.

Is there an action for what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct action `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`.

But to check for roaming use this

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if(ni != null && ni.isRoaming()) {
  // device is in roaming state
}
```

NOTE: There seems to be a bug on certain versions, where getActiveNetworkInfo() returns null if roaming. See here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11866

Comment: No that action is not triggered when the device is handoffed to a foreign network. The roaming part is working fine for me.

Comment: See the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619049/unable-to-instantiate-receiver-in-broadcastreceiver-sms

Comment: My BroadcastReceiver is well built. I know this because it receives an intent when I activate/deactivate my wifi antena or 3g/4g data.
@Rami Jarrar I'm not exactly sure what you wanted me to get from that post.. Although its true that when we go on roaming usualy the device gets a warning SMS, which I could use to check if I'm roaming. But I don't think that's the best approach, because I would have to check everytime a sms is received.